For an iOS AppIntent, is it possible to return a URL to a file within the app's sandbox?
AppIntents can return IntentResults of varying types. One of the supported types is a URL. I would like to be able to use the URL to a file within the app's sandbox and return this as an IntentResult so that it can be used in another Shortcut.
While testing this with the simulator in a Shortcut, I am successfully able to return the URL to a file stored within the app's sandbox (i.e. - the documents directory) and feed that result to another Shortcut. This however doesn't seem to work on a real device. I've tried allowing access to local documents via the UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace keys but that hasn't seemed to make a difference.
I also tried returning an AppEntity that implements the Transferable protocol, along with a @Property of type URL, and then tried accessing that within a Shortcut. In this case, I was again only able to access the URL on the simulator and not on a real device.
Is there an extra entitlement or plist value I'm missing somewhere that is preventing me from handing off the URL on a real device?

Have you tried creating a shared container for your app group? I assume your shortcut can also access your app group code. You can create the container using let sharedContainerURL = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.yourcompany.yourapp"). After that, move or copy the file you want to share into that container and send the URL of the copied file to the shortcut
